# API to add principals to Kerberos

Tags: macos, rest, kerberos

I am trying to kerberize my RESTful backend and I am not seeing anywhere in the GSS-API documentation how could I **add** a user/service - i.e., I understand the **authentication** process with GSS-API, but not the **signup** process. To make my question simpler : **kinit** is the command line tool used to add principals, is there an equivalent for GSS-API ? If the answer is no - should I go and look at the kinit source code and port it to my project (using system("kinit ...") raises security questions/problems so I am not thinking about using it) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Users should be added to the Kerberos database using API provided by Kerberos Distribution Centre. In Microsoft Active Directory, KDC uses LDAP as its database, so users can be added/removed using JNDI, as described here: http://cyberlizard.livejournal.com/120080.html.

kinit not a tool for adding users but for (simply speaking) "logging in", or (technically speaking) it's a tool that "obtains and caches an initial ticket-granting ticket for principal" (see: http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-devel/doc/user/user_commands/kinit.html), i.e. it takes credentials (i.e. for example principal and password, connects to KDC and tries to receive initial TGT from it. Client).

Comment: I am planning on Kerberizing a Unix application, so it would helpful to do Kerberos on Linux/Mac OS. Where can I find more infos on the KDC API ?

Comment: In which language is this application written? There should be a high-level library, which you could use to interact with your KDC. For example in C it's GSS-API, in Java JGSS.